# Testing nested ng-repeat in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I had been doing trial and error to select and click the following code unsuccessfully, since I am brand new to Protractor I am probably missing something.

**HTML**

```
<table id="sample-table-1" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover no-bottom-margin feedback">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Service
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
            Rating
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="feedbackService in feedbackServices" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">Feedback Service One</td>
            <td>
                <div rating="" score="feedbackService.rating_id" max="5" id="34" updaterating="updateScore(ratingId, id)" class="text-center ng-isolate-scope">
                    <div class="rating">
                        <a ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-mouseover="hover($index)" ng-mouseleave="stopHover()" ng-class="starColor($index)" ng-click="setRating($index)" class="ng-scope rating-normal">
                            <i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-class="starClass(star, $index)"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-mouseover="hover($index)" ng-mouseleave="stopHover()" ng-class="starColor($index)" ng-click="setRating($index)" class="ng-scope rating-normal">
                            <i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-class="starClass(star, $index)"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="feedbackService in feedbackServices" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">Feedback Service Two</td>
            <td>
                <div rating="" score="feedbackService.rating_id" max="5" id="30" updaterating="updateScore(ratingId, id)" class="text-center ng-isolate-scope">
                    <div class="rating">
                        <a ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-mouseover="hover($index)" ng-mouseleave="stopHover()" ng-class="starColor($index)" ng-click="setRating($index)" class="ng-scope rating-normal">
                            <i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-class="starClass(star, $index)"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-mouseover="hover($index)" ng-mouseleave="stopHover()" ng-class="starColor($index)" ng-click="setRating($index)" class="ng-scope rating-normal">
                            <i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-class="starClass(star, $index)"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to click anything that is clickable above.
**TEST**

```
it('should rate feedback services', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('feedbackService in feedbackServices')).then(function(arr) {
       console.log(arr);
        var rowElems = arr.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
        rowElems.then(function(cols){
            var stars = element.all(by.repeater('star in stars')).then(function(starArr) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
                    starArr[0].click();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    browser.debugger();
});

xit('feedback services', function() {
    var rows = element.all(by.repeater('feedbackService in feedbackServices'));
    rows.last().then(function(row) {
        var rowElems = row.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
        rowElems.then(function(cols){
                // Not sure if this is the right approach either?

        });
    });
});
```

I was also able to setup debugger in Webstorm, but I was not able to inspect variables, there was lot of unnecessary data there.

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st test it('should rate feedback services', function() {, your script has issue from this line

```
var rowElems = arr.findElements(by.tagName('td'));
rowElems.then(function(cols){
```

you should change it to

```
arr.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function(rowElems) {
element.all(by.repeater('star in stars')).then(function(starArr)
```

The same for 2nd test

```
element.all(by.repeater('feedbackService in feedbackServices')).then(function(rows) {
```

I re-write your tests as below, I didnot test it

```
it('should rate feedback services', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('feedbackService in feedbackServices')).then(function(arrs) {           
        arrs.forEach(function(arr) {
            arr.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function(rowElems) {
                var cols = rowElems.length;
                element.all(by.repeater('star in stars')).then(function(starArr) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
                        starArr[0].click();     
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

it('feedback services', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('feedbackService in feedbackServices')).then(function(rows) {
        rows[rows.length-1].then(function(row) {
            row.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function(rowElems) {
                rowElems.forEach(function(rowElem) {
                    rowElem.getText().then(function(text){
                        console.log(text);
                    });                 
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I should have rather posted the error as well. I still get this with your update  `Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'findElements'`. The HTML converts to a table with two columns, and 2nd column of each row having two stars which I need to click. I am not even able to get to the second column yet :(

Comment: @hmajumdar, I've just update the script. Sorry for any inconveniences

Comment: It produces similar error  `Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findElements'`. Also I am not sure how the above code can click on the second column elements.

Comment: I already run it succeed on my machine. Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub




Feedback Service Two


Stack Overflow Demo
    should rate feedback services
    feedback services

Finished in 2.507 seconds
2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures

Comment: starArr[0].click(); should probably be starArr[i]